# GET shows 304 in django and test fails when entries are listed

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, get

in my django app,I am using a css file and some images for my web pages.I have defined the media_root and media_url as

in settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/me/dev/python/django/myproject/mysite/media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/site_media/myapp/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/'
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
'/home/me/dev/python/django/myproject/mysite/myapp/myapptemplates',
)
```

The media folder contains

```
myapp/css and myapp/img folders
```

full path of base.html is

```
/home/me/dev/python/django/myproject/mysite/myapp/myapptemplates/myapp/base.html
```

In the above base.html,I am putting the css and images as

```
<head>
<title>myapp</title>
<LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="{{MEDIA_URL}}css/mystyle.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA="screen, print"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}img/my-icon.ico"/>
<div id="header">
    <img class="centerpage" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}img/mypic.gif" alt="MY WEB APP PIC">
 </div>
```

When I am trying to list all entries I created in my app,everything shows up properly.But I see 304 response code for GET on the css and images.
(I am using django1.1.1 so, I have not used any csrf_token in the templates.)
The terminal output by django is

```
[04/Sep/2011 18:15:18] "GET /myapp/entries/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3843
[04/Sep/2011 18:15:18] "GET /site_media/myapp/css/mystyle.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[04/Sep/2011 18:15:18] "GET /site_media/myapp/img/mypic.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[04/Sep/2011 18:15:18] "GET /site_media/myapp/img/navigation1.png HTTP/1.1" 304 0
```

As you can see ,the view returns 200 where as the GET on css and images return 304.
The style and images are properly shown on the webpage though.

Also,on a maybe related issue, when I test the following view,it fails.

```
@login_required
def entries_list(request,template_name,page_title):
    entries=get_entries_of_user(request.user)
    dict={'page_title':page_title ,'entries':entries}
    req_context=RequestContext(request,dict)
    return render_to_response(template,req_context)   

 class BaseTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
      super(BaseTestCase,self).setUp()
      self.client.login(username='me',password='me')
 class EntryTest(BaseTestCase):
   fixtures=['entries.json']
   def test_entries_list_view(self):
       print 'reverse=',reverse('myapp_entry_list')
       response=self.client.get(reverse('myapp_entry_list'))
       status_code=response.status_code
       print 'st code=',status_code
       entries=get_context_variable(response,'entries')
       self.assertEqual(200,status_code)

   def get_context_variable(response,name):
      print 'response_context=',response.context
      return response.context[name]
```

The print on status code here gives

```
st code= 302
```

The print on  response.context prints 'None' and a type error is raised when response.context['entries'] is tried

```
in get_context_variable
    return response.context[name]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable
```

I couldn't figure out why this happens.Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting confused with the way MEDIA_URL uses the absolute path defined by MEDIA_ROOT.

When you make a request to `'/site_media/myapp/'` it will look at the top level of MEDIA_ROOT (in this case `'/home/me/dev/python/django/myproject/mysite/media/'`). If you request `/site_media/myapp/css/mystyle.css` then it will look for MEDIA_ROOT/css/mystyle.css which resolves to: `'/home/me/dev/python/django/myproject/mysite/media/css/mystyle.css'`. You should either change MEDIA_URL to `/site_meda/` or change MEDIA_ROOT to `'/home/me/dev/python/django/myproject/mysite/media/myapp`.

Hopefully this explanation cleared things up for you.

Comment: thanks..that cleared up things for me .Still I couldn't find out why the test fails.I am calling client.login in the superclass..Still the client.get(reverse(someurl)) gives a 302 response.

Comment: I would create another question for the last part.